# Display img from an Id in Django

Tags: python, django, regex, url, request

In my Django work in progress website, I have a folder with more than a thousand of thumbs, with an Id inside their names, just like this :
*the_name_of_the_thumbnail_123456_low.png*

This Id is retrieved from a request from a database. For displaying the corresponding picture on my site I have to build the url string, maybe like this : {% static images/low/the_name_of_the_thumbnail_ {{var}} _low %}.

How can I perform this task ? With regex, from the template ? or another way ?

Thank's a lot

Answer (score 0):

the cleanest way would be to store the filename in a variable in the view function. Something like this:

```py
"""
views.py
"""
def my_image_view(request):
    image = models.Image.objects.first()  # for example, you have a better way to get it from the DB :)
    file_name = f"images/low/the_name_of_the_thumbnail_{image.id}_low.png"
    context["file_name"] = file_name  # or however else your context dict is called
    return render("template", context=context)
```

```html
<!-- my_image_template.html -->
<img src="{{ file_name }}" alt="..." />
```